# Independence of a variable in an Equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have an equation which contains a variable for example 'n' how do we extract a relation from this equation when it is independent of 'n'?

For instance:

If

## $\frac{p\left(2a+\left(pn-1\right)d\right)}{2a+\left(n-1\right)d}$

is independent of ***'n'*** we have the relation **d=2a**.

Well I obtained this result by equating the equation to a constant and isolating 'n' at one side and equating the resulting term to zero.

(ie)

## $\frac{\left(2aK-dK+pd-2ap\right)}{p^2d-d}=n=0$

(where K is the constant equated to the main equation.)

Which on simplification gives:

## d=2a

I got the right answer but I want to know whether the approach is correct or the answer I got is just a matter of coincidence.

Comment: There are special cases, such as $p=1$.

Comment: So can't I use it to obtain any relation from a certain equation? Or is the above one a special case?

Answer (score 1):

You "isolated" $n$, and for situations where the procedure is correct, you got an $n$  uniquely determined by the parameters $a,d,p$ and the hidden parameter $K$.

So the conclusion is that the ratio cannot be a constant independent of $n$ **except** possibly where your isolating procedure breaks down. In particular, the $d=2a$ is not right.

The isolating $n$ procedure breaks down when it involves division  by $0$.  So the only *candidates* for independence are situations where $p^2d-d=0$.

Comment: So do you mean that the answer d=2a is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect. You can easily verify directly that if $d=2a$ and $p\ne 1$, then your ratio is not independent of $n$.